# glDrawArrays does not draw anything in GL_TRIANGLES mode

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

My problem is the `glDrawArray` command stops working. I've written a few programs which I used that command. However now, I don't have any idea why it doesn't work.

But I still can draw lines to the screen with `GL_LINES` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Mesh.h"
#include <iostream>

Mesh::Mesh()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    size = 0;
}

void Mesh::AddVertices(const Vertex vertices[], int length)
{
    size = length;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::Draw()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, Vertex::SIZE * 4, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Draw is always called by Game class. And my Vertex class:

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex(glm::vec3 pos)
{
    this->pos = pos;
}

Vertex::Vertex(float x, float y, float z)
{
    pos = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
}

glm::vec3 Vertex::GetPos() const
{
    return pos;
}

void Vertex::SetPos(glm::vec3 pos)
{
    this->pos = pos;
}
```

Comment: If you use multiple mesh objects, you might get into trouble with your VAOs, since you only set them in the constructor. So if you allocate 2 meshs before filling the first, you change the wrong VBO in `AddVertices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. When I initialize my OpenGL functions, I have accidentally written `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` instead of `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(vertices)` is `sizeof(void*)`, because in C or C++ arrays in function arguments decays to pointers. You should use `length` provided in second argument, if it is size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. First of all, size of the argument length is not in bytes. But I tried to convert it (length * sizeof(GLfloat) and length * sizeof(float)). Still doesnt't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: From what I'm able to see in your code fragment, length is count of vertices; each vertex have several floats. So size should be `length * sizeof(Vertex)`. Aside from that, I think every programmer must do himself/herself a favor and just forget "doesn't work" sentence. What errors are generated? Have you tried `KHR_debug` extension to trace down a problem?

Comment: I think I've just tried `KHR_debug`, if I'm not wrong. And there was no errors. I also tried `length * sizeof(Vertex)`. I changed the AddVertices function a little bit. I added an array of GLfloat: `GLfloat data[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0 };` and passed it to the glBufferData like I've done it my projects before that. The result is same. Something is hiding from my eyes but I cannot find it.